# Remapping keyboard in BIOS

Tags: keyboard, bios

I want to change a key function in BIOS. My down arrow key is broken. I couldn't change boot options on the boot options screen. Because I have to use down arrow key. That's why I remap my down arrow key. I don't use the right CTRL(this is just an example). I don't want to remap in Windows. Is there any way to change key functions in BIOS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

no because there is no way of changing them unless you change your layout or get a external keyboard my AYTRGFJKBVGU keys are broken lol so i use a desktop keyboard via USB and a bluetooth one too.